# How to get ZWJ (Zero-width Joiner) entity to work with Japanese characters?

Tags: html

Is there any way to get the zero-width joiner character (&zwj; / &#8205; / &#x200D;) to work with Japanese characters? Or is there a similar solution that doesn't involve wrapping characters in HTML tags?

I want to reproduce the result of a pre/nobr/white-space:nowrap but without wrapping the individual character. I also want to do this only to select groups of characters (to avoid wrapping in the middle of a word).

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GbvFk/1/

or:
&#x65E5;&zwj;&#x672C;&zwj;&#x306E;&zwj;&#x30B5;&zwj;&#x30F3;&zwj;&#x30D7;&zwj;&#x30EB;&zwj;&#x30C6;&zwj;&#x30AD;&zwj;&#x30B9;&zwj;&#x30C8;

I have these strings in i18n properties files, where they look like JS escapes (\u65E5\u200D, etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ZWJ doesn't do what you want, zero-width joiner works only on "complex scripts" like Arabic, it doesn't just hold the characters side by side, it actually joins the shapes.

I think the best and cleanest way to do this is exactly to wrap any multi-character word you don't want to break in a nowrap span.

Also something to consider is that no robot expects some weird character be in the middle of any two characters so if your pages are going to be online no search engine will be able to read them.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to disable wrapping, the best way to do that is with CSS.