# Zero width inline element moves justified text node contents

Tags: javascript, html

I have a justified text node into which I want to insert an inline placeholder ( element if you like) whose only content is a "`&zwj;`" that shouldn't have any width (and chrome inspector says as much too). I have noticed that when I insert this node inline into the text node, the whole line "jiggles" as if recalculating the layout, although this  should not affect it.

I have also tested that if the text node I insert it into is left-aligned, this slight movement does not happen. Is this just inherent to the way the browser calculates text placement in a justified text element or could there be any workaround for this?

Comment: Can you make an example on jsfiddle.net that shows this behaviour? i have tried, but failed to recreate it, weather or not i inject `<span>&wzj;</span>` or i have a preplaced span and inject the `&zwj;` into that. you can see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sort of is the spirit of my question... If you click on the div, it inserts randomly a `<span>&zwj;</span>` and when you click you notice that the text moves as if repositioning. Try a few times if you don't catch the effect at first!
http://jsfiddle.net/e7Ne2/1/

Comment: Weird man. Very subtle in Chrome 13. Its not the same words that move every time either. It varies with each run through. Had to look reallly close to catch it.

Comment: yeah that's the random function, I've just updated it so it always inserts the span on the first line. the problem is sometimes I have to do it a few times in quick succession so it is a visible effect
http://jsfiddle.net/e7Ne2/2/

Comment: Hmm it doesn't happen if you insert it before a blank space only when you insert it inside a word. I would call this a bug report, I don't see a work around.

Comment: For what it's worth, this also happens in latest (stable) Opera.

Comment: Apparently &zwj; does not work with non "complex script" character sets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444184/how-to-get-zwj-zero-width-joiner-entity-to-work-with-japanese-characters

Comment: The zero-width joiner (`&zwj;`) is used to adjust character joining behavior in certain complex scripts. Implementation behavior is undefined when it's placed between characters that don't have joining behaviors. Undefined behavior should generally be avoided like the plague.

It's not really possible to give you good advice without more detail about what you're trying to do. What's the purpose of inserting the span containing only a ZWJ?

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, the issue, rather no issue, is due to the way "justify" works. First to confirm that "justify" text-align is causing this, check the jsffidle : http://jsfiddle.net/e7Ne2/29/

Both divs are same -> except that First div has `text-align: justify` and the other does not.

You will see that first div shows that behaviour but not second div.

This is because "justify" works this way (from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justification_%28typesetting%29)):

> In justified text, the spaces between words, and, to a lesser extent, between glyphs or letters (kerning), are stretched or sometimes compressed in order to make the text align with both the left and right margins.

So, when we introduct a `&zwb;`, the text gets reorganized. This behaviour not consistent because not all characters are modified with `&zwb;`. So, when `&zwb;` alters the text, few letters "may be" stretched/compressed leading to the seemingly weird behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The best I can find on it is that support for the zwj is not complete in all browsers. Your code is taking the inserted span tag and removing it with that .text() call, so it's unwrapping the zwj and causing display issues wherever it lands between letters.

I'm not sure what the end application is supposed to be, but using the jQuery .html() function would probably be better (you'll just need to check and make sure you're not writing inside of a tag), because the .text() function strips tags.

Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/text/